# iterating through pose bones to change Euler

Tags: python, bones, pose-mode

I'm trying to change all the pose bones Euler with a script. My failed idea is this:

```
for bone in bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones:
print(bone)
```

This gives me

```
<bpy_struct, PoseBone("thigh_ik_target.R") at 0x7f8061bafef8>
```

But all I need is just the name of the bone.

```
"thigh_ik_target.R"
```

So can use

```
for bone in...
```

To loop through all the bones to change the "rotation_mode" with

```
bpy.context.object.pose.bones[bone].rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
```

Should I try and extract the name of the bone from that printed statement and put it in a variable?

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265915/get-list-of-selected-objects-as-string-blender-python) post

```
import bpy

selection_names = bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones

for i in selection_names:
    bone = (i.name)



    bpy.context.object.pose.bones[bone].rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
```